# Multithreading application and Threadsafe Lists

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've been working in a multithread application and I'm still trying to figure the best/most efficient way to deal with a List that's being used and changed by multiple threads.

I've seen that writting a Threadsafe class for a List is not really the best option and to be honest I find all the locking somewhat messy.

I've thought about converting it into a ConcurrentDictionary as I've been using these and they seem to behave really good.

However, I've tried a different approach and would like to hear some opinions on this if it's or not a good option to take:

```
if(MyList.Count > 0)
{
    MyStruct[] Example = null;
    Example = new MyStruct[MyList.Count];
    MyList.CopyTo(Example, 0);

    foreach(MyStruct B in Example)
       //Code here
}
```

This is just something that I tried and seemed to work without really having to make changes anywhere else. I'm not sure if I should even be doing this, that's why I'm looking for some opinions on this

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not thread-safe.

Consider two threads for simplicity.

1. Thread A creates the list with 10 items
2. Thread B sees the list has 10 items, and creates an array for 10 items
3. Thread A adds an item to the list, so it now has 11 items
4. Thread B crashes on CopyTo, since the array isn't big enough

And that's one of the sanest things that can happen.

Don't mess around with multi-threading at random. It's messy, dangerous and you'll be left with plenty of bugs that are hard to reproduce and fix. Unless something is explicitly said to be thread-safe, don't assume any thread-safety at all. Obligatory starter on multi-threading: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

The usual checklist goes something like this:

1. Is it really necessary to have multi-threading in the first place?
2. Are you *sure* sure?
3. Are there thread-safe classes that do exactly what you need?
4. Can you use a simple, consistent locking architecture that is guaranteed not to deadlock?
5. Are you *really sure* you need to share that object between multiple threads?
6. Seriously, multi-threading is hard. Could you perhaps do with immutable data that's explicitly passed between the threads, rather than having shared mutable state?
7. Find the simplest correct way you can handle the synchronization between the threads.
8. Is it good enough? Good, stop.
9. It's not good enough? Consider alternate approaches to data sharing.
10. If you still have a bottle-neck on a shared resource, consider lock-less programming. *This is much, much harder than lock-based synchronization. Make sure you know what you're doing.* Even the people who designed C#/.NET are very wary of lock-less programming. Even Raymond Chen, and that's the Chuck Norris of software engineering. There be lions. You need perfect understanding of everything that is and isn't guaranteed, and what is safe on your platform and what's common to all the platforms.

Comment: I particularly liked point 10 and the comment "There be lions".

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create an array of structs. Just use the CopyTo with another List or ToArray.

Additionaly, you can use BlockingCollection which is thread-safe for Producer Consumer operations.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx